# GeoPDF: How to create a hierachy of layers in which I can select all the sublayers from the parent layer?

Tags: pdf, geospatial-pdf, geopdf

I am trying to create this

[image]

Having a look at this example and the PDF specs (optional content configuration dictionary keys), I am quite confused about how to create that vs what I have at the moment

[image]

Any suggestion on which dictionary key / setup I should look into?
Note: I manipulate the PDF header programmatically (with PyPDF2) and I am *not* interested in Acrobat Reader options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to make sure that the parent object is an OCG and **not** a string.

```
/Order [ 25 0 R [ 22 0 R 23 0 R 24 0 R ] 21 0 R ]
```

and not

```
/Order [ (mystring) [ 22 0 R 23 0 R 24 0 R ] 21 0 R ]
```

So if you don't have a natural candidate you want to designate as the parent, you need to create an additional OCG with the name you want.